# Как получить краткую информацию из Википедии через Mediawiki API?

Tags: php, mediawiki-api

Если кто-нибудь знаком с API Википедии, напишите, пожалуйста, функцию получения краткой информации о чем-либо по запросу (ну или хотя бы самой страницы в читаемом виде) на PHP.   Так и не понял, как такое реализовать. Просто у меня, если и получаю страницу, то с `wikitext` разметкой. Как краткую информацию получить вообще не понял (и возможно ли такое).

Answer (score -1, accepted):

- **`API MediaWiki`** находится по адресу: `~/api.php`.
- [Справка по **`MediaWiki API`**](http://goo.gl/G6unp).